# Change slider direction

Tags: swift, uislider

I would to change a slider's direction from right to left. I want 0 to be on the right side.

For example:

[image: Reversed slider]

My slider:

```
let slider = UISlider()
slider.minimumValue = 0
slider.maximumValue = 0
slider.isContinuous = true
slider.tintColor = UIColor.red
slider.value = 0
slider.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
```

I'm not sure if this is possible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just flip the slider horizontally:

```
slider.transform = CGAffineTransform(scaleX: -1, y: 1)
```

Comment: oh thank you so much, What's the default scale that im using now x:1 y:1 ?

Comment: @Salah Yes, the default is `scaleX: 1, y: 1`.

Comment: Better to use this https://stackoverflow.com/a/59918314/1442541

Answer (score 2):

in my opinion its more easier and more official to use following:

```
slider.semanticContentAttribute = .forceRightToLeft
```

Comment: @evya I agree, this one is cleaner.

Answer (score 1):

Or take the slider value with

```
let realValue = slider.maximumValue - slider.minimumValue + slider.value;
```

And set it using

```
slider.value = slider.maximumValue - slider.minimumValue + realValue;
```

Like that the slider does not need to be visually transformed, and will still respond correctly to any other input methods (keyboard, accessibility input, etc)